# How to simplify java route in mac terminal

Tags: java, eclipse

If I have    eclipse-workspace/bin/test/example.class  in my mac
I try `java example` (in test folder, use mac terminal)
But it doesn't work just say

> Error: Could not find or load main class haha

But it works `java test/example` (in bin folder)
How can i declare just 'java example' in test folder?
(I probably think it's about PATH, but i can't find solution...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to the `java` executable **is not a file**. It's a fully qualified class name. To run such a name, java needs to know where the class file lives (as well as the class files for any types mentioned in it, of course) - and it does this by searching the classpath (not the `PATH`), which *are* file system paths - you can specify either a jar file, or a directory. Either way, the class files need to exactly match the full names, e.g. the full name of the String class is `java.lang.String`. It's the package + the name (`String.java` starts with `package java.lang;`).

It's not clear whether you have told eclipse that `bin/test` is the base folder, or if `bin` is the base folder and your example class has `package test;` at the top.

You'd run something like this:

```
java -cp ~/eclipse-workspace/bin/test example
# or - depends on that package stuff
java -cp ~/eclipse-workspace/bin test.example
```

It gets more complicated if you have deps involved. Then it might look like:

```
java -cp ~/eclipse-workspace/bin:'~/eclipse-workspace/lib/*' test.example
```

Note the single quotes: You do *NOT* want bash (your shell) to expand that star. It also depends on your eclipse config. Your question cannot possibly be an eclipse config, or at least, not without some *wildly* odd setting shenanigans - normally it's `workspace/projectname/bin/fully/qualified/package/YourClass.class` - i.e. `workspace/projectname/bin` is the classpath. Not `workspace/bin`.

Comment: There are lots of shortcuts. You can write a shell script, for example. Or you can set up your build system to produce runnable jars (just doubleclick the jar / run `java -jar thejar.jar`).